# Is MySQL unique row swap atomic?

Tags: mysql, unique-constraint, atomic

I've come to the conclusion that the only way to swap two rows where the value to be swapped is part of a unique constraint, is to update row 1 to a temporary value outside the normal range (such as a negative number for an INT column), change row 2 to the previous value of row 1 and change row 1 to the previous value of row 2.

Simplified example:

```
SELECT uniquevalue1 AS prev1 FROM sometable;
SELECT uniquevalue2 AS prev2 FROM sometable;

UPDATE sometable SET uniquevalue1=-1;
UPDATE sometable SET uniquevalue2=[prev1];
UPDATE sometable SET uniquevalue1=[prev2];
```

Followed by a commit.

This works fine, no problem, but:

Is this operation safe to use?

Imagine a unique constraint on a default (signed) INT(11) column where you swap temporarily to -1 and then follow the pattern described above - with autocommit disabled, of course.

What happens if you perform these two swap operations at the same time? Will the lack of a commit until after -1 is no longer the value of any rows mean that the statements will not collide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not execute two or more statements at the same time. They are always executed one by one.

However, if you use a transaction (remark: This will only work for tables of innodb type, not myisam) this opteration will either fail with no changes left or succeed. A second swap that also tries to use the number -1 will be locked until the first transaction finishes.

Comment: I never said I'd do it in one statement. The example would be three statements in total followed by a commit.

However, if you are correct then you have confirmed my initial understanding that what I am doing is OK,.